# How to style child component html elements to parent component grid?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component with a grid defined, I want to style a child component input elements so that they stay in a specific grid row and column; I tried doing this;

```
parent component html;

    <div class="patient-details-grid">
            <app-child-component></app-child-component>
    </div>

    .patient-details-grid {
       gap: 15px 40px;
       grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
       display: grid;
    }

    app-child-component {
    .form {
      display: block;
      .firstName {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 2;
      }
      .lastName,
      .year,
      .city,
      .zipCode,
      .phone,
      .email {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
      }
    }
```

The form elements do not get placed into the correct grid tracks as I expected. How do I style these child elements into the parent div grid? the child component has multiple input elements like this;

```
<input type="text" class="firstName">
<input type="text" class="lastName">
<input type="text" class="year">
<input type="text" class="city">
<input type="text" class="zipCode">
<input type="text" class="phone">
<input type="text" class="email">
```

Comment: Please share code, if possible a stackblitz and screenshots of expected output!

Comment: @NarenMurali added some more code, working on a stackblitz